# How to Extract SVG children html tag from xml file using linq in C#

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a xml file in MVC web project as following:

```xml
<Navigation>

 <item>
   <CoreId>1010</CoreId> 
   <p>
   <svg width="640" height="480" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     <!-- Created with SVG-edit - http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/ -->
     <g>
       <title>Layer 1</title>
       <rect height="170" width="258" y="136.67" x="188" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="#ff0000" id="svg_1"/>
     </g>
   </svg>
  </p>
   <Privilege>ADMIN</Privilege>
   <MenuID>10811010</MenuID>
   <ParentMenuID>1081</ParentMenuID>
   <ResourceKey>AP_Template</ResourceKey>
 </item>
```

And I try to get the svg data from the item with the menuId == 10811010;

Here is my C# code:

```
public string GetVPFCore(int vpfCore)
{
    VPFCore _localitem = new VPFCore();

    try
    {

        var element = from item in xmlController.Root.Descendants("item")
                      where (string)item.Element("MenuID") == vpfCore.ToString()
                      select new
                      {
                          _data = item.Element("p").ToString()
                      };
        foreach (var t in element)
        {

            _localitem.Data = t._data;
        }
        return _localitem.Data;

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw new IOException("The XML item was not found!");
    }

}
```

Why I can't get the svg data without embedding it into a `<p>` tag.

The scope of this function is to extract only svg data without the `<p>` and inject it into a cshtml view.

Comment: Well what happens when you *don't* have the `p` tag? I would strongly recommend against catching `Exception` and making an *assumption* about what the problem is like this - it may well be an entirely different issue. It would really help if you could provide a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. (And why are you using an anonymous type when you're only providing a single property that you then extract? Why create a `VPFCore` object, just to set and then retrieve a single property? There's *much* simpler code you can use for the same effect.)

Comment: Not obviously - it's just returning a string... so what does repeatedly setting that `Data` property and then returning the value from fetching it do that couldn't just be done by returning `element.Last()`, having changed the `select` clause to `select item.Element("p").ToString()`? We still don't know what goes wrong without the `<p>` tag, and we still don't have a short but complete example...

Comment: Thank you Jon, The function primarily was designed to operate on a customized object, VPFCores, which the Data member suppose to contain the actual data coming from DB repository. I have changed that service into an xml as I was asked to. But, totally agree, anonymous object is abundant here. I would remove it. when I get null.

Comment: Sure, I am in the San Fransisco Airport departing for an other city. Give me few hours, I will update this question. I have to catch the plan. But, yes, my question was as Martin mentioned regarding the svg namespace, and why replacing the <p> tag with <svg> element, the query returns null. I will update the sketch. Thank you all for the contribution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the `svg` element then you need to take the namespace into account so define

```
XNamespace svg = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
```

then `item.Element("p").Element(svg + "svg")` gives you the root element of the embedded SVG document.

Comment: Can I ask what the role of "svg" string is? It adds svg string front of all pre-existing svg tags: <svg:svg width="640" height="480" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <!-- Created with SVG-edit - http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/ -->
  <svg:g>
    <svg:title>Sample</svg:title>
    <svg:rect height="170" width="258" y="136.67" x="188" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="#ff0000" id="svg_1" />
  </svg:g>
</svg:svg>

Comment: I have used an `XNamespace` object constructed from a string, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387093%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for details on that with LINQ to XML. As my code suggestion simply uses the `XNamespace` to select a node in your sample, I don't directly see why you say you get a prefix `svg` in the markup. Maybe you can edit your question with details on the code that produces the result.

Comment: I think the problem is unrelated to to element selection, it is simply caused by your input having `<svg width="640" height="480" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">` and the default serialization that LINQ to XML does when there are two namespace declarations for the same namespace. I realize that can be a problem if you want to output HTML5 with SVG as text/html (when namespace prefixes are not allowed) but I think it is a different problem which needs a separate question.